# Command Prompt (Windows 10)

Tags: cmd, prompt, google-geocoding-api

estoy sincronizando mi sitio web en github.com con mi ordenador. Para ello debo "comprometer" (commit) algunos documentos primero. Para ello se debe usar un comando especifo. Cuando lo hago, me aparece que primero debo decirles quien soy. Desconozco el comando para ello. Necesito poder resolver esto para continuar con la sincronizacion. Porfavor Ayuda

[image: A contnuacion una imagen de lo arroja el CMD]

Comment: Te lo dice allí: `run` que significa `corre`. Debes ejecutar esas líneas, cambiando el valor de correo y nombre por los tuyos.

Comment: solo has lo que te dice, ejecuta los comandos y coloca un nombre de usuario y gmail